# Работа bat в фоновом режиме

Tags: bat

Я создал простой .bat файл с запросом `start https://mysite/change_proxie`
При запуске этого .bat происходит запрос на смену ip прокси.
Однако при таком исполнении открывается и окно браузера, что не есть хорошо.

Как сделать так, чтобы был выполнен запрос к url https://mysite/change_proxie в фоновом режиме, без открытия окон командной строки и браузера?

Comment: читайте справку `bitsadmin /?`

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, посмотрел, но так не понял как это применить на практике. Без системных знаний сложно что то понять. Я человек который не знает нюансов создания каких-либо скриптов. Есть необходимость, пытаюсь как рядовой пользователь найти решение. Благодарю за совет